# show and edit route of a resource controller got 404 not found error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a `master.php` file contain some routes of may laravel project. like this :

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'master',
    'as'     => 'master.'
], function () {
    Route::get('/login', 'MasterController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/login', 'MasterController@masterDoLogin');

    Route::group([
        'middleware' => ['auth:master']
    ], function () {
        Route::get('dashboard', ['as' => 'admin_dashboard', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@index']);

        Route::group(['prefix' => 'websites', 'as' => 'websites.'], function () {
            Route::get('websitesDatatable', ['as' => 'websitesDatatable', 'uses' => 'WebsiteController@websitesDatatable']);
        });
        Route::resource('websites', 'WebsiteController');
    });
});
```

After running `php artisan route:list` below routes returned that shows all thing is right :

```
  | GET|HEAD  | master/dashboard                                 | master.admin_dashboard                    | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@index                              | web,auth:master                                      |
|                           | POST      | master/login                                     | master.                                   | App\Http\Controllers\MasterController@masterDoLogin                         | web                                                  |
|                           | GET|HEAD  | master/login                                     | master.                                   | App\Http\Controllers\MasterController@showLoginForm                         | web                                                  |
|                           | POST      | master/websites                                  | master.websites.store                     | App\Http\Controllers\WebsiteController@store                                | web,auth:master                                      |
|                           | GET|HEAD  | master/websites                                  | master.websites.index                     | App\Http\Controllers\WebsiteController@index                                | web,auth:master                                      |
|                           | GET|HEAD  | master/websites/create                           | master.websites.create                    | App\Http\Controllers\WebsiteController@create                               | web,auth:master                                      |
|                           | GET|HEAD  | master/websites/websitesDatatable                | master.websites.websitesDatatable         | App\Http\Controllers\WebsiteController@websitesDatatable                    | web,auth:master                                      |
|                           | DELETE    | master/websites/{website}                        | master.websites.destroy                   | App\Http\Controllers\WebsiteController@destroy                              | web,auth:master                                      |
|                           | PUT|PATCH | master/websites/{website}                        | master.websites.update                    | App\Http\Controllers\WebsiteController@update                               | web,auth:master                                      |
|                           | GET|HEAD  | master/websites/{website}                        | master.websites.show                      | App\Http\Controllers\WebsiteController@show                                 | web,auth:master                                      |
|                           | GET|HEAD  | master/websites/{website}/edit                   | master.websites.edit                      | App\Http\Controllers\WebsiteController@edit                                 | web,auth:master
```

Routes like `master/websites`, `master/websites/create`, `master/websites/websitesDatatable` worked fine.

But other route like `master/websites/1` or `master/websites/1/edit` does not recognized and always return **404 not found** error.
I do not know what is problem ?

if anyone know , please help me.

Comment: How do u refere to those ? By name or url ?

Comment: simple as a get request on browser : `http://loverspay.local/master/websites/1`

Comment: where you define this route `master/websites/{website}`? I cannot see in your `master.php`

Comment: How the signature of your `show` and `edit` actions look? I'm wondering if you're expecting a model, like `public function edit(Website $website)`, and you don't have a model instance for the given PK `1`.